# Errors executing bash script: Permission denied; No such file or directory

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm just getting started with Ubuntu. I am trying to create a script that will do the following:

1. Perform an `ls -al` on the files within a user's home directory and then save it to a file in my directory.
2. I want to save the tree information for the home directory into a file called tree.dat in my directory.
3. Create a new directory in my home directory called `backups`.
4. Move the files I created to that new directory.

The issue I'm running into is I keep getting a permission denied error. It tells me my home directory does not exist even though it should.

Here is my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cd /home
ls -al > ls.txt
tree/home>tree.txt
mkdir backups 
cd backups 
mv -t /home/backups ls.txt tree.txt
mv ls.txt ls.bu
mv tree.txt tree.bu
```

This is the output:

```
luse@luse-VirtualBox:~$ sudo 777 script1.sh
sudo: 777: command not found
luse@luse-VirtualBox:~$ chmod 754 script1.sh
luse@luse-VirtualBox:~$ ./script1.sh
./script1.sh: line 4: ls.dat: Permission denied
./script1.sh: line 5: tree.dat: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `backups': Permissions denied
mv: failed to access '/home/backups': No such file or directory
./script1.sh: line 8: cd: backups: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'ls.dat': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'tree.dat': No such file or directory
luse@luse-VirtualBox:~$
```

[image: screenshot of terminal showing error messages]

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a few things wrong.

1. A user's home directory is `/home/<USERNAME>`, *not* `/home`.
2. You need a space between `tree` and the path.
3. The specific `mv` command syntax you used to move the `.txt` files into the `backups` folder must come *before* `cd backups`.

Taking all these into account, your script should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~
ls -al > ls.txt
tree ~ > tree.txt
mkdir backups
mv -t ~/backups ls.txt tree.txt
cd backups
mv ls.txt ls.bu
mv tree.txt tree.bu
```

**Notes:**

1. `~` is the shorthand for `/home/<USERNAME>` *for the current user*, you can also use `/home/<USERNAME>` in place of `~` to specify the user.
2. Since you're writing a script, I presume you would run it more than once. Running the script for the second time would throw an error *unless you delete* the `backups` folder *before* running the script again. To overcome this, you need to change the `mkdir backups` command to `mkdir -p backups`.

Comment: If you don't want to assume a user's home directory is in /home, you can use `user_home=$(getent passwd $user | cut -d: -f6)`

Comment: @glenn It's a Ubuntu setup for a beginner after all... Nevertheless, it's a good point, please feel free to edit that in perhaps as note number 3.